# AMP: <amp-ad> not showing adense ads, but empty field

Tags: html, ads, adsense, amp-html

I'm having problem with amp-ad.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async custom-element="amp-ad" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:9000/simple-test.html">
    <title>AMP Test</title>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="content">
        <div style="width: 728px; height: 90px">        
            <amp-ad width=728 height=90
                type="adsense"
                data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXX">
            </amp-ad>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not being displayed. Instead there is element with specified dimensions, it inserts some scripts and iframes, but there's no ad in there. I tried all available layouts. I also tried with different ad sizes. The code is ok according to validator.

Traditional JavaScript versions works fine.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> < link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:9000/simple-test.html">

Adsense AMP ads are not shown on local development sites. Uploading this to a live site will probably work. Also make sure that your domain is whitelisted in the adsense settings.

Comment: It does work in localhost, but for an ad code, it is not guaranteed that an ad will surely be delivered. So the ad might not be delivering at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create an account on on Google for Publishers to get AdSense on your website. The site will guide you through it. You can also check out the DFP ad test page. Hope that helped :-)